# Windows 10 multiple BSODs on a clean installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

Recently I started geting BSODs (MEMORY_MANAGEMENT, SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDELED and KERNEL_SECURITY_CHEK_FAILURE) on my Windows 10 computer and after ruling out the usuall suspects (running sfc, chkdsk, Memory Diagnostic Tool and updating all drivers) I decided to reinstall the sysytem. I performed a clean installation onto a new hardrive and yet I'm still getting the BSODs. WhoCrashed analysis of the DMP files points the source of the BSODs to `C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe` and `ntkrnlmp.exe` files

Do you have any idea what I can do to fix the issiue?

DMP files: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LFoDKE5wTD8JpnxvdMHUnee1vKGCauvr

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 16299) (16299.rs3_release.170928-1534)
System Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
System Model: GA-990XA-UD3
BIOS: Award Modular BIOS v6.00PG
Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 640 Processor (4 CPUs), ~3.0GHz
Memory: 8192MB RAM Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 671MHz (9-9-9-24)
Graphics: 1023MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560 Ti (MSI)
Monitor 1: SM2333TN (1920x1080@60Hz)
Monitor 2: FPD1775W (1280x720@60Hz)
Storage: 232GB Western Digital WDC WD2500AAJS-08L7A0 ATA Device (SATA), 1863GB TOSHIBA DT01ACA200 ATA Device (SATA)
------------
```

Comment: Given the nature of the bugcheck.  Can you run verifier.exe.  Use standard settings and I would probably specifically check all non-Microsoft drivers from the list.  Once set, reboot, next time it happens the next dump may help to identify the corruption taking place rather than the result later on.

Comment: I set it up. Will report back after the next bsod

Comment: Ok, thanks to your tip I was able to trace the cause of the problem to my mouse driver.Thanks for help

Comment: Glad it helped.  To help others with the issue it might be worth posting the version and name of the driver as the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Don’t forget to re-run verifier to disable it all.